# Typeahead not working with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, autocomplete

I am working with typeahead and jquery. my code is not working. I need to make this typeahead work in my code and I am calling it like this but I am not getting any result. I need suggestion also in textbox. but it's not working.

```
var availableTags = [
"Apple",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"];

(function () {

alert("hello");
$('#searchInput').typeahead(
[
{

prefetch: availableTags,
source: availableTags

}
]);

});
```

I have a input text with id=searchInput, but I am getting nothing. Is this the right way? I have made references to the following files also:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="engine.js" >
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="typeahead.min.js" >
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="typeahead.js" >
</script>
```

I also need to understand how typeahead gets called. Is it anonymous function or can be called on events?

Comment: This old question was/is rather unclear, I wonder if it could be deleted? It seems to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specifics about using `typeahead.js`? And you have two times loaded `typeahead.js` and `typeahead.min.js` that are basic the same `javascript` file.

You can try with `autocomplete` from `jquery-ui` library.

Basic example from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ looks like this.

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
```

And HTML look like:

```
<input id="tags" />
```